Should I recommend with reservation or omit reference?
I have recently worked with one of my least capable students in recent memory. Here are a few specifics:

He has a great attitude
He has great difficulty communicating in English for technical and non-technical purposes.
In terms of technical skill, he has some high level expertise but very little low level expertise and seems to pick up new concepts relatively slowly.

Ultimately, he was able to complete his assigned tasks with notably more assistance compared to peers.
Based on other referral forms that I have seen, I expect to have the option to "recommend with reservation", which I would be willing to do, but I do not want to hamper or harm his learning journey.
Do we have empirical information on whether omitting to refer is better for student outcomes such as acceptance rate or other outcomes of interest compared to "recommend with reservation"?
One more note on the context of this conversation: This student made it clear that he intends to go for graduate school prior to taking my class and asked whether I would recommend contingent on his performance, to which I agreed. So again, I'm happy to recommend him, but these forms ask about whether he's a top 1, 10...% and I think he is genuinely in the top 50% at best.

You might want to change your username to something less identifiable...

Have you had contact with this student in other than this class? How extensive is your knowledge of their overall work?

No I haven't. Our course content is in software engineering and I have seen his portfolio, which is the only further knowledge that I have.

How can "one of the least capable students" be anywhere remotely close to the top 50% of students? Shouldn't that be more like "bottom 10-20%" (or "top 90%", if that sounds better)?

@TooTea I said "top 50% at best" and yes technically I think top 70-80% is accurate but I typically don't see those in the referral forms. So perhaps 50% is a categorical rounding of 70%. I think top 50% is about as far as some forms go. I could justify top 50% of engineer students (not only my students) on the basis that my typical student performs above average, his good attitude, and also he is "one of the least capable" among those who "complete his assigned tasks" so he did not fail he's just at the bottom of the passing group

I think you should tell the student you cannot provide them with the glowing recommendation that programs likely expect.

So again, I'm happy to recommend him, but these forms ask about whether he's a top 1, 10...% and I think he is genuinely in the top 50% at best.

I don't know if I would express it to them quite so bluntly, but I think you should communicate this: they've done well in your course, but that graduate schools often ask if you can place the applicant in the top 1% or 10% of all students and that you won't be able to answer "yes" to that question.
I would encourage them to seek other recommendations, but if they insist then think it's then entirely up to you whether or not you agree to still write a letter if the student, after knowing your letter will be lukewarm, still wants your recommendation.
If, in fact, you really mean that this student is "one of my least capable students in recent memory" then I guess I am a bit puzzled why you are concerned with the acceptance rate of students like this. If the programs are competitive, and this student is among the least capable at their current level, it may not be to their benefit at all to advance to that level and be overwhelmed. There are many successful career paths that do not involve graduate school.

It isn't exactly clear what the state of the request is. If the student has already informed the institution(s) that you are a reference then it may be too late for the following. I hope not.
I strongly suggest that you have a talk (face to face if possible) with this student and tell them about any reservations and that you would need to communicate them in any LoR. Let them decide, with full knowledge, whether you should be a recommender or not.
The talk with the student can be productive in other ways. Knowledge of your reservations might put them on a better path.
I'll note that your point 1 (attitude) can help with your 3 (slow learner) if they understand that they may need to do more work than they might think to build a career.
I once had an undergrad student in an upper level course who had previously never had a really positive educational experience. He was thought of as marginal-at-best by the faculty. I simply treated him differently and invited him to spend as much time as he wanted during office hours asking questions and such. It sort of drove me crazy, but in the end, he wound up at the top of my course without any accommodations made. He was so good, in fact, that the normally "top" students, and they were very good, thought I'd thrown in a "ringer".
Your situation is more serious, since a "recommendation" that isn't really a recommendation can destroy a potential career. They need to know and understand that before you act. I treat that as a moral imperative, though comments here suggest that isn't a universal view. Do. The. Right. Thing.
